# simulate java enum objective-c

Tags: objective-c, enums

in java an enum can be declared like this

```
enum MyEnum {
  ONE("descr for one"),
  TWO("descr for two");

  private String descr;

  MyEnum(String descr) {
    this.descr=descr;
  }

  public String getDescr() {return this.descr;}
}
```

therefore we can always call myEnumInstance.getDescr() for getting enum description. It is possible of course to add several variable in constructor and create its corresponding accessor.
Is there anything similiar in objective-c ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Unfortunately for you, there is nothing similar in ObjectiveC.

You can have a Helper Class mapping enums to NSString* though...

Something like this:

```
typedef enum {
   kONE,
   kTWO
} MyEnum;
```

And then a class method/message somewhere:

```
+ (NSString*) getDescriptionFor:(MyEnum)e
{
    switch(e) {
        case kONE:
             return @"descr for one";
        case kTWO:
             return @"descr for two";
        default:
             break;
    }
    return @"";
 }
```